# DCT slow to accelerate once engine is warmed up

Tags: hyundai, tucson, dual-clutch-transmission

We've got a 2018 Hyundai Tuscon and we've recently noticed that it takes a long time to get going from a stopped position once the car is warmed up. First thing in the morning when the car is cold, it drives fine, but once the temp gauge gets to 11 or 12 o'clock, accelerating from a stopped position takes an extra 1-2 seconds before the car actually moves. This feels especially scary when making turns at red lights because it looks like we are just rolling cluelessly for 2 seconds.

There are no engine lights or codes being alerted.

If I use the sport shift mode, and keep the car in first gear, the problem happens consistently. It is not starting in second gear.

In neutral, hitting the gas hard immediately shows high RPMs so I assume it's the transmission.

We recently had an (engine) oil change at the dealer where they used some kind of "extended oil treatment" which is said to help "expand the seals and extend the life of the oil change", etc. Car has less than 20k miles.

Why would this sort of thing happen only when the car is warmed up?

Comment: You had the oil in the transmission changed? or the oil in the engine?

Comment: engine @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: The engine oil or additive would have most likely have nothing to do with what you're describing. It seems to me the transmission is trying to start in second gear, like it was in "limp home mode". You could test my theory by putting the gear selector in manual shift mode when stopped and checking to see what the gear indicator is saying ... at least I'm assuming this option is available to you. If not, then I'd have to think your DCT is slipping once warmed up. If all fails, I'd bet your Hyundai is still under a powertrain warranty. Agree with you, though, it sounds like a transmission issue.

Comment: Any codes in the computer?

Comment: @Moab There are no engine lights or codes being alerted, per the dealer.

Comment: There may be memory codes in the computer, they need to be checked with a code reader.

Answer (score 2):

Take the car into a dealer/certified Hyundai repair shop and ask them to check (or replace) your Boost Pressure Sensor Harness.

I had this same problem in my 2017 Hyundai Tucson Sport, if I'm understanding you correctly. When I would try to accelerate, the engine would rev up but no acceleration would be applied for about 1-2 seconds, which felt very scary in situations you describe or driving in icy/snowy conditions, for example.

When I took the car in to have this problem identified, the mechanic told me the Boost Pressure Sensor Harness was loose/faulty and was either repaired or replaced. Since then, I have not experienced this issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random thought: I recently test drove a Hyundai and the start\stop feature on it had a very slow reaction time. Does yours have this feature and if so, try turning it off on your next trip and see if the problem goes away after it warms up.

Comment: You may be referring to the Sport and Eco modes. Unfortunately this problem happens in all drive modes.